# Get text from edittext and receive to listview ( 2 different intents)

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I have a problem to receive a text from edittext in one activity intent to a listview on another intent.

This is what I have done so far:

Activity B:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(addnote.this, MainActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("text", edit.getText().toString());

                startActivity(i);
```

Activity A: where the list view is I just don't know how to receive this text when I clicked the button 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**thank you for that but I have problem receiving the data and placing it into my list view in my activity A i have done so far :**

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String mdata = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
ListView listv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notelist);
ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mdata);
listv.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

Comment: These spots are meant for answers. Posting an additional question here will confuse people. You should add an Update location in your originally question, with this revised new question. When you do so, also include more details. As it stands I see no reason why this code won't work. What exactly is the problem? As in what's not happening? Also show more of the function so we can better figure out the problem.

Comment: as you can see on the first question, activity B is sending the edit text data but activity A ( first intent ) is not showing the result in list view which I'm trying to display is... the code in activity A is what I have posted by mistake in the second answer ... but it's not working.... it says : **The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity, int, String) is undefined**. what am I missing ? thank you very much !!!

Comment: I edited your code to how it should look. Try that. Should work fine.

Comment: it's not working at all because in your code you are not using any listview to put the string from the second activity from edit text. you have just getting back the string... I have a problem to place the data I have received from edit text in activity B to place it to list view in activity A, as you can see from the code I have wrote in the **ANSWER** by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Basically all you want to do is call `getStringExtra()` to grab whatever you originally assigned during `putExtra()`. So for example: In Activity A's `onCreate()`, you'll want to do this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

    mYourString = getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
}
```

Keep in mind, that Android recommends prefacing the names of the objects your storing with the application's package name.  So instead of using `"text"` you should use `"com.example.myproject.text"`.